# Two columns in from[ ] , one column in to[]

Tags: android, database, simplecursoradapter

I have next problem. I have three columns in DB (id integer, picture_int integer(picture from resourse), picture_galery( path) and I want to set images from DB in listview. I want to check, if column picture_int is null, set image from column picture_galery and if picture_int!=null then set this picture. Sory for my english=(

Comment: i don't know wath i should to try. I think maybe write own adapter, but i doesn't know how, second my idea to save BLOD in BD in one column all picture

Comment: Well save the path of the image rather than saving the image itself if u dont want to store images as blobs

Comment: i know it, but how to make this? Two columns in from[ ] , one column in to[] in simpleCursoreAdpapter. Is it necessary to write own adapter?

Comment: two columns in a single field of the database?
If this is what you are intersted better try to give a delimiter between the two words and split when accessing it back

Comment: No, read my question please

Comment: If i understood the question well ... your db has 3 columns 1.id 2.picture_int 3.picture_gallery....... If the 2nd column is null you want to set the third column value as the picture image in the list?
Is this your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom adapter by extending a BaseAdapter and overriding the required methods

```
 public int getCount() {
   return somevalie;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int arg0) {
  return arg0;
 }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int arg0) {
   return arg0;
 }

  @Override
  public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

return view
}
```

For more info look at [Custom Adapter Sample](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/custom-list-view.html)

and later create the database which you can access for setting the images to the custom list view.
suppose consider like

```
if(theFieldYouAccess == null)
{
 //Do what you want
}
else
{
 //Do what you want
}
```

In the getView() functionality

Comment: Can i extending SimpleCursorAdapter and override only one or two methods?

Comment: Yes we can do either way i think... I have been into Base adapter since a long time...